# Align decimals in tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I am creating a table like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Caption here}
\begin{tabular}{@{}
                c 
                l 
                l 
                S[table-format=2.1] 
                S[table-format=2.2] 
                S[table-format=2] 
                S[table-format=1]
                @{}}
\toprule
{Tree} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{Local}\\ {name} \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{Scientific} \\ {name} \end{tabular} & {Diameter} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{Tree} \\ {height} \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{Measured}  \\ {branches}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{}\\ {order} \end{tabular} \\
\midrule
1 & Local name A & \textit{Scientific name A} & 10.1 & 45.54 & 40 & 1 \\
2 & Local name B & \textit{Scientific name B} & 20.2 & 54.45 & 50 & 2 \\
3 & Local name C & \textit{Scientific name C} & 30.3 & 20.02 & 60 & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{label here}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I put the column names between {} to avoid siunitx having problems reading it like text (siunitx will try to read "ee" from Tree as exponent).

If I use `{@{} c l l c c c c @{}}` instead of what I propose, it gives me a pdf. If I use the first `S[table-format=2.1]` also gives me a pdf. Once I put the other one, TexMaker does not compile anymore. It takes like 10x to finish and gives me errors `! Missing control sequence inserted<inserted text>\inaccessible...e} \end{tabular} & {DBH} & \begin{tabular}`

Does anyone know why?

Also, the line "name " in "Scientific name" is not aligned left. How can I aligned it left?

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simpler code with `makecell` which compiles. The contents of the `\makecell` or `\thead` commands accepts line breaks, and is centred by default, both vertically and horizontally. These commands must be surrounded by a pair of braces in `S` columns.

I also loaded `cellspace` to ensure a minimal vertical padding of cells in columns with specifier  prefixed  with the letter `S`   (or `C` if you also load `sunitx`, as is the case here), and `caption` to obtain a sensible distance between caption and table

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, cellspace, caption}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2.5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}}
\caption{Caption here}
\begin{tabular}{@{}
                c
               Cl
                l
                S[table-format=2.1]
                S[table-format=2.2]
                S[table-format=2]
                S[table-format=1]
                @{}}
\toprule
{Tree} & \makecell{Local\\ name} & \makecell{Scientific\\ name} & {Diameter} & {\makecell{Tree \\ height}} & {\makecell{Measured\\branches}} & {\makecell{\\order}} \\
\midrule
1 & Local name A & \textit{Scientific name A} & 10.1 & 45.54 & 40 & 1 \\
2 & Local name B & \textit{Scientific name B} & 20.2 & 54.45 & 50 & 2 \\
3 & Local name C & \textit{Scientific name C} & 30.3 & 20.02 & 60 & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{label here}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to wrap the entire `tabular` in `{}`, not just the content of the `tabular`. However, a macro for the tabular might be helpful. The `name` in `Scientific` name is not left aligned because you used a `c` column in the `tabular`, you need an `l` column.

I think I would use `\begin{tabular}[b]...` for the `tabular` in the header row, so that the vertical alignment is along the bottom row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\quicktab[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}#1@{}} #2 \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Caption here}
\begin{tabular}{@{}
                c 
                l 
                l 
                S[table-format=2.1] 
                S[table-format=2.2] 
                S[table-format=2] 
                S[table-format=1]
                @{}}
\toprule
Tree &
\quicktab{Local \\ name} &
% the optional argument to \quicktab sets the column type for the nested table
% use l for this one
\quicktab[l]{Scientific\\name} &
{Diameter} &
% note the nested tabulars are placed inside {} in the three next rows
{\quicktab{Tree \\ height}} &
{\quicktab{Measured \\ branches}} &
{\quicktab{ \\ order}} \\
\midrule
1 & Local name A & \textit{Scientific name A} & 10.1 & 45.54 & 40 & 1 \\
2 & Local name B & \textit{Scientific name B} & 20.2 & 54.45 & 50 & 2 \\
3 & Local name C & \textit{Scientific name C} & 30.3 & 20.02 & 60 & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{label here}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```